# Why is BigQuery converting a Firebase user_property to an int?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

We have mobile (iOS and Android) and web platforms streaming events into Firebase, which are then exported to BigQuery. However, the way BigQuery is treating `user_properties` is different between the mobile and web platforms. I understand that in Firebase, all user properties are strings. In the mobile platforms, a particular user_property is showing up as a string, while on the web platform, it is being converted to an integer (`user_property.value.string_value` vs `user_property.value.int_value`). Is there something I configure to stop BigQuery from inferring types here? Am I misunderstanding how BigQuery imports user_properties?

Does BigQuery perform a similar inference for `event_params` as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you take a look at this page? https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765

Comment: @rmesteves what part of that page? I have seen that page, and do have the projects linked

Comment: That was more about the question you removed. But it seems that the schema is not possible to change: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en

Comment: @rmesteves I was confused about what question your answer was trying to address; sorry for moving it to a different page. I'm still not sure if that addresses my problems with the intraday table, but thanks nonetheless.

Comment: Also, the schema is consistent. The issue is that different struct field values (the string one vs the int one) are being populated depending on the uploaded data & (more importantly) platform

Comment: This seems to be a particularity for the the platforms. You can not change this kind of configuration when linking Firebase to BigQuery

Comment: @rmesteves Are you saying this is out of my control, or has to do with my setup for the different platforms? p.s. Thanks for all the help

Comment: I mean this is something out of your control

Comment: @rmesteves if you post the platform message as an answer, I will mark this as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [document](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765), the `BigQuery` export works like a plug and play solution and the tables are created automatically in BigQuery.

Given that, you can't control which columns to export or how to represent the data in the exported table. If you need to cast the type of data in the mentioned field, I suggest that you use a **view** between your table and your final query.